# Javascript changing values inside a iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events, cross-domain

I have my website

**[www.aplicatii-iphone.ro](http://www.aplicatii-iphone.ro)**

and another

**page.html on localhost**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Object References across Iframes</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){
    var form = document.getElementById('testForm');
    form.testBtn.onclick = sendData;
}

function notify() {
    //alert('iframe loaded');
    var iframeEl = document.getElementById('ifrm');
    if ( iframeEl && iframeEl.parentNode && document.createElement ) {
        var newTxt = document.createTextNode('The iframe has loaded and your browser supports it\'s onload attribute.');
        var newPara = document.createElement("p");
        newPara.className = 'demo';
        newPara.appendChild(newTxt);
        iframeEl.parentNode.insertBefore(newPara, iframeEl);
    }
}

function sendData() { // to form inside iframed document
    // frames array method:
   // window.frames['ifrm'].document.forms['ifrmTest'].elements['display'].value = this.form.testEntry.value;
    var ifrm = document.getElementById('ifrm');
    var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
    var form = doc.getElementById('search-input'); // <------<< search input
    form.display.value = this.form.testEntry.value;
    form.submit();
}

// test in iframed doc
var counter = 0;

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="testForm" action="#">
<p><input type="text" name="testEntry" size="30" value="[enter something]" /> <input name="testBtn" type="button" value="Click Me" /></p>
</form>

<iframe name="ifrm" id="ifrm" src="http://www.aplicatii-iphone.ro" onload="notify()" width="900">Sorry, your browser doesn't support iframes.</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

And every time I press the button <kbd>Click Me</kbd>, I want that the state of [www.aplicatii-iphone.ro](http://www.aplicatii-iphone.ro) to be like a user searched for that value written in "testEntry" from outside of the iframe.

I tried something there ... but I can't figure it out ... any help please?

I took the example from here http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs.php

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatly, this is not possible due to the [Same orgin policy](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs.php#access).
And changing the `document.domain`-value only helps if you try to connect a subdomain with the main-domain.

**Edit**
If you avoid the same-orgin-problem by using a page on the same website, this should work for you:

```
window.frames['ifrm'].document.getElementById("search-input").value = document.getElementsByName("testEntry")[0].value;
window.frames['ifrm'].document.getElementById("cse-search-box").submit();
```

Comment: so you say that is beacause my browser? i read articles that you cannot do that due to this "Same orgin policy."

Comment: Did I say that is because of your browser? :-D You are right, it's due to the "Same orgin policy".

Comment: so The same origin policy is a security feature of JavaScript that prevents access to properties and methods of documents from different domains. In other words, if the containing document and the iframed document are not from the same domain, attempts to reference each other's objects will result in access denied or similar error messages. ........... is mi answer?

Comment: look , i put it on the same domain, and still didn't work http://www.aplicatii-iphone.ro/iframe.html

Comment: @RowMinds you might have a look at <input>'s placeholder http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp attribute (Yes, I know, http://www.w3fools.com, but w3schools is right here, or at least right enough).

Comment: now i get it .. you dont need to actualy use xpath, or dom to get to that element, getElementById should do the job ... but this will only work on the same domain? aplicatii-iphone.ro/iframe.html Thank you

Comment: Yes, you have to put the file on the same domain, or at least on a subdomain (then you have to use document.domain)

Answer (score 3):

If you know you're using a modern browser, you could use postMessage to communicate between the frames. Here's a good write-up: http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-window-messaging-with-html-5-postmessage

If you need to support legacy browsers, you could use [Google Closure's](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/) [CrossPageChannel](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/net/xpc/crosspagechannel.js?r=1024) object to communicate between frames.

Comment: ok, but there is  a small example, when i have a page that have many tags, do i have to use xpath? because i find id hardy to get to the "search-input" value ...

Comment: Really thanks for the postMessage link, upvoting once is not enough!